# Python: different results on CMD, IDLE and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python.
I can't understand why, working with a simple bit of code, I can see a result in a jupyter notebook and in IDLE (>>>) but not in CMD when launching a .py file
The code is:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("datasets/file.csv")
df.head()
```

Why can't I see the result in the CMD when launching the xyz.py file, while I can see it in the notebook through the xyz.ipynb file or through the IDLE (>>>) ?
The code is the same, the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame.head(n) returns the first n rows of the dataframe.
This however does not print it:

```
print(df.head())
```

Will print the head.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter and IDLE execute python code in interactive mode, which doesn't require the print function. In contrast, running python xyz.py is not in interactive mode, so nothing shows up with how you have your code written.

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv ("datasets / file.csv")
 print(df.head())
```

will print df.head() in both jupyter notebooks and when it is run as python xyz.py

Answer (score 0):

Interactive environments like IDLE are meant for easy *interactive* exploration, so they automatically print the value of each expression. If you want to check the value of some variable `var`, it's easier to just type `var`, than `print(var)`.

But when you run a Python script non-interactively, you need to explicitly print what you want to print:

```py
print(df.head())
```

Overall, if you're not typing some instructions on the spot, but writing a script for later use, you should always do that.